# execution variable type for multi instance task assignee

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco, activiti

I'm trying to build a workflow that implements the following process:

when a user receives a task, he has two options:

1. Doing the task by clicking task done
2. Transferring the task to multiple assignees using mutliple instance task.

I'm saving the assignees(association) in an execution variable and then try to use it in the next user task.

workflow bpm file:

```
<userTask id="doOrReassign" name="Do Or Reassign" activiti:formKey="swwf:DoOrReassign">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string>
                execution.setVariable('swwf_ActionsToDo', task.getVariable('swwf_ActionsToDo'));
                execution.setVariable('swwf_assignees',task.getVariable('swwf_assignees').toString());
            </activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <userTask id="delegatedTask" name="DelegatedTask" activiti:assignee="${assignee}"> 
       <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" activiti:collection="${swwf_assignees}" activiti:elementVariable="assignee"></multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
    </userTask>
```

workflow model:

```
<type name="swwf:DoOrReassign">
            <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
            <properties>
                <property name="swwf:ActionsToDo">
                        <type>d:text</type>
                        <default>Approved</default>
                        <constraints>
                        <constraint name="swwf:ActionToDoOptions" type="LIST">
                            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                                <list>
                                    <value>TaskDone</value>
                                    <value>ReAssign</value>
                                </list>
                            </parameter>
                        </constraint>
                    </constraints>
                    </property>
            </properties>
            <associations>
                    <association name="swwf:assignees">
                        <title>Assignees</title>
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>false</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>cm:person</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
             </associations>
            <overrides>
            <property name="bpm:outcomePropertyName">
                    <default>{http://smartway-me.com/model/workflow/1.0}ActionsToDo</default>
                </property>
            </overrides>
        </type>
```

when I click the reassign button, I get the following error

```
${swwf_assignees}' didn't resolve to a Collection
```

Answer (score 1):

In your workflow definition you are assigning swwf_assignees with:

```
execution.setVariable('swwf_assignees',task.getVariable('swwf_assignees').toString());
```

toString() transforms the list into a string.